# UISwitch does not execute properly when an Outlet is created Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiswitch

I have a UICollectionViewCell class that contains outlets to UIImageView,UILabel and a UISwitch. 
In the UICollectionViewController class I have an action for the switch

```
    class CollectionViewController:UICollectionViewController{

     var cell = GridCell()

    @IBAction func stateChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
        var indexPath:NSIndexPath
        indexPath = self.appCollectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(self.appCollectionView.convertPoint(sender.center, fromView: sender.superview))!
        print("Index path",indexPath.item)


        if cell.switch.on{
            cell.switch.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            Print("Switch turned on")
        }
        else{

            cell.switch.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell.switch.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(ApplicationConfig.cornerRaduisUISwitch)
            cell.switch.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()         
        }

    }
}
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        cell = applianceCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GridCell
        cell.label.text = applianceName[indexPath.row] as String
        cell.image.image = UIImage(named: "ic_notifications_18pt")

        return cell
    }
```

And This is my GridCell class

```
class GridCell: UICollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var switch: UISwitch!
}
```

When I click on the switches only the switch in the last cell executes switch.on condition.

All other switches execute the else condition even on turning on the switch.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please put whole action method.

Comment: I have a question: do the switch outlet in UICollectionViewCell or UIColletionViewController?

Comment: The switch outlet is in UICollectionViewController

Comment: But your question said it is inside GridCell, Confirm that

Comment: The switch outlet is in UICollectionViewCell class but the action is in the UICollectionViewController

Comment: I meant the switch action is in UICollectionViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are checking whether a cell variable in your class has a switch that is on rather than checking whether the `sender` is on.  The last assignment to the cell variable in your class will end up being the last cell in the CollectionView.  On the other hand, the sender will be the switch that was clicked.

Here's an example:

**PhotosViewController.swift**:

```
import UIKit

class PhotosViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let photosDataSource = PhotosDataSource()

    @IBAction func clickedSwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
        let cell = sender.superview!.superview as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
        let labelText = cell.label.text!
        print("\(labelText) - ", terminator: "")

        sender.on ? print("On") : print("Off")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        collectionView.dataSource = photosDataSource
    }

}
```

**PhotosDataSource.swift**:

```
import UIKit

struct Photo {
    var image: UIImage
    var title: String
}

class PhotosDataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var photos: [Photo] = []

    override init() {
        super.init()

        photos.append(
            Photo(
                image: UIImage(named: "1downarrow")!,
                title: "down arrow"
            )
        )

        photos.append(
            Photo(
                image: UIImage(named: "5_heart")!,
                title: "5 of hearts"
            )
        )

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)
        -> Int
    {
        return photos.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
        -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let identifier = "UICollectionViewCell"

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell

        let photo = photos[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageView.image = photo.image
        cell.label.text = photo.title
        return cell
    }
}
```

**PhotoCollectionViewCell.swift**:

```
import UIKit

class PhotoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!

}
```

**Assetts.xcassets**:
[image]

**Main.storyboard**:
[image]

Here's what it looks like:

[image]